# Angular/Jade/UI Bootstrap + Inline Javascript

Tags: angularjs, pug, linkedin-api, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to load LinkedIn inline profile (example [here](http://developer.linkedinlabs.com/jsapi-console/#examples/member/inline.html)) in a UI Bootstrap modal.

I'm using the exact same code in the [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). The modal works, but the LinkedIn inline profiles are not generating.

Any clue why?

```
<!--OUTPUT-->
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" class="ng-scope">
        <script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-id="https://www.linkedin.com/pub/kelsey-garvey/1a/954/75" data-related="false" data-format="inline">
        </script>
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" class="ng-scope">
        <script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-id="https://www.linkedin.com/in/lindsayahearne" data-related="false" data-format="inline">
        </script>
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" class="ng-scope">
        <script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-id="https://www.linkedin.com/pub/sean-gustilo/1/117/876" data-related="false" data-format="inline">
        </script>
    </li>
</ul>

//-JADE
script#myModalContent(type='text/ng-template')
    div.modal-header
        h3.modal-title I'm a modal!
        div.modal-body
            ul
                li(ng-repeat="item in items")
                    script(type="IN/MemberProfile", data-id="{{ item}}", data-related="false", data-format="inline")

//CONTROLLER
    $scope.items = [
      "https://www.linkedin.com/in/jeffweiner08", 
      "https://www.linkedin.com/in/williamhgates",
      "https://www.linkedin.com/in/barackobama"
    ]

    $scope.open = function (size) {

      console.log($scope.connections.used)

      var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
        size: size,
        resolve: {
          items: function () {
            return $scope.items;
          }
        }
      });

      modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
        $scope.selected = selectedItem;
      }, function () {
        $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
      });
    };

    $scope.inputInit();
    $scope.timerStart();
    $scope.inputReset();
      $scope.connectionNext();
  });

angular.module('whoDatMemberApp').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    connection: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

Comment: Could you provide the output HTML ? After it has been processed by Jade and Angular. Maybe just a right click on the modal -> inspect, right-click the html element, copy as HTML, paste here.

Comment: I guess you have to load a LinkedIn library to bring these script tags alive. Maybe some functions of such a library are called on page load, doing the work; If it's the case you would maybe need to call it again, after the angular has bound the script tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LinkedIn library parses the document when the library is finished loading, and activate script tags that are in the DOM *at that moment*.

If any LinkedIn **script tags appear later** in the DOM, the library isn't watching it, so it wouldn't know. You have to ask the library to **parse it again**.

This answer should be of help https://stackoverflow.com/a/5728329/1057958.

Your ModalInstanceCtrl controller should call

```
IN.parse(domNode)
```

after *items* have been bound to the $scope.

*domNode* being the root node you want to parse down, so you should get a reference to your modal element and pass it to *IN.parse*